# Why this UIImage can't release

Tags: ios, uiimage, didreceivememorywarning

I wanna save an image To sandBox...  My app often crash and give MemoryWarning when I have saved many images.....

this is the code:

```
-(void)saveCurrentLine:(NSDictionary*)lineInfo
{

UIImage* saveImage=[lineInfo objectForKey:@"saveImage"];
NSString* savePath=[lineInfo objectForKey:@"SPN"];
NSLog(@"The savePath is :%@",savePath);
NSString* docs=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject];
NSString  *pngPath = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",noteBookName,savePath]];
NSLog(@"%@",pngPath);
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
UIImage* saveJPG=[lineInfo objectForKey:@"saveImage"];
UIImage* saveJIV=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@IV",pngPath]];
NSString  *pngPathS = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Scan/%@",noteBookName,savePath]];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self addImage:[self scaleToSize:saveJIV size:CGSizeMake(256, 192)] toImage:[self scaleToSize:saveJPG size:CGSizeMake(256, 192)]], 1.0) writeToFile:pngPathS atomically:NO];
NSLog(@"line save over and [saveJPG count] is %d [saveJIV count] is %d [lineInfo count] is %d",[saveJPG retainCount],[saveJIV retainCount],[lineInfo retainCount]);
}
```

---

I found that the saveJPG and saveJIV does not release and I can't release them ....How can I let them release????

All method for this function:

```
 -(void)ChangeCanvasTo:(NSNotification*)CanvasInfo
{
self.layer.opacity=1.0;
savePageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",PageName];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSDictionary *currentLine=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:saveImage,@"saveImage",savePageName,@"SPN",nil];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(saveCurrentLine:) toTarget:self withObject:currentLine];
NSString *pngPath=[[CanvasInfo userInfo] objectForKey:@"PageName"];
PageName=pngPath;
NSLog(@"will change to %@",PageName);
NSString* docs=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject];
UIImage *resumeCanvas=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",noteBookName,PageName]]];
drawStep=RELOAD;
curImage=resumeCanvas;
[curImage retain];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[resumeCanvas release];
[currentLine release];

}

-(void)saveCurrentLine:(NSDictionary*)lineInfo
{

UIImage* saveImage=[lineInfo objectForKey:@"saveImage"];
NSString* savePath=[lineInfo objectForKey:@"SPN"];
NSLog(@"The savePath is :%@",savePath);
NSString* docs=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject];
NSString  *pngPath = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",noteBookName,savePath]];
NSLog(@"%@",pngPath);
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
UIImage* saveJPG=[lineInfo objectForKey:@"saveImage"];
UIImage* saveJIV=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@IV",pngPath]];
NSString  *pngPathS = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Scan/%@",noteBookName,savePath]];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self addImage:[self scaleToSize:saveJIV size:CGSizeMake(256, 192)] toImage:[self scaleToSize:saveJPG size:CGSizeMake(256, 192)]], 1.0) writeToFile:pngPathS atomically:NO];
NSLog(@"line save over and [saveJPG count] is %d [saveJIV count] is %d [lineInfo count] is %d",[saveJPG retainCount],[saveJIV retainCount],[lineInfo retainCount]);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the `addImage...` method you're calling? I'd suspect that the problem is somewhere in there. Also, where does the `lineInfo` dictionary come from? Using `retainCount` is completely useless btw, see http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Comment: - (UIImage*)addImage:(UIImage *)image1 toImage:(UIImage*)image2
   {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image1.size);
    [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image1.size.width,image1.size.height)];
    [image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image2.size.width,image2.size.height)];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}   ---------This is the addImage method

Comment: Hmm, that looks harmless, so where is `lineInfo` coming from? Do you perhaps have an array of all the `lineInfo`s you're calling this with or something like that?

Comment: Btw, you should add this sort of thing by editing the question, not as a comment. It's hard to read code in the comments.

Comment: OK,I will show all method about this function

Answer (score 0):

The way ARC works is in adding "release" messages automatically when it understands the object is not used any more. What you can try is adding `saveJPG = nil; saveJIV=nil;` at the end of yor method.

That way ARC will realize it is allowed to release them since they're not used anymore.

Comment: That won't do anything. Those are local variables, they will be released as soon as the method returns.

Comment: I don't see a reason it won't be releasing with the code he just posted, but since he said thats the situation - I suggested he'l try that regardless. Doesn't hurt.

Comment: I don't either, so the problem has to be somewhere else. Setting these variables to `nil` is just a placebo. It doesn't *hurt*, but it also won't have any effect whatsoever.